# Is there any method in ruby or in python to convert pdf to xml

Tags: xml, pdf, doc

Recently I have got an requirement like i need to convert pdf files to xml.So please tell me how to do it in python or ruby programming languages.
  please reply to my question as early as possible
   your help would be appreciated..

Comment: Do you want to extract data from the PDF and put it into an XML file or do you want to represent the PDF as XML (with all its layout information)?

Comment: i just want to extract data from pdf and put in an xml. But I would like to know another method even,so please tell me both the methods

Answer (score 4):

Use [pdftohtml](http://pdftohtml.sourceforge.net/).

It can be installed with `brew install pdftohtml`. This adds `pdftohtml` to your path.

So, to convert pdf to xml, you can run `pdftohtml -xml your_file.pdf your_file.xml`

In python, you could use these lines:

```
import os

cmd = 'pdftohtml -xml your_file.pdf your_file'
os.system(cmd)
```

!note that pdftohtml automatically adds the 'xml' extension to your second file input

Comment: I know this is a really old post but just in case someone stumbles on it I would recommend: brew install poppler

It has pdftohtml packaged with it and has more features and is still supported.